# Trouble in the proof of Theorem 1.1. in the book Structure of the Real Number System

Tags: induction, number-systems

### The Question

> **THEOREM 1.1** *There is exactly one natural number which is not the successor of any natural number.*
>
> PROOF: Let $N_S$ be the range of $S$. By Axiom $A_2$, there exists a natural number $u$ which is not in $N_S$. Let $M=\{u\}\cup N_S$. Then $u\in M$ and $S(n)\in M$ for every $n\in M$, since $N_S\subset M$. By Axiom $A_3$, $M=N$. Hence $N=\{u\}\cup N_S$, and every natural number $n\ne u$ is in $N_S$, i.e., every natural number except $u$ is the successor of some natural number.

### My Understanding

My trouble is that I can't understand the key point, that are the words "exactly one". If I add another natural number $u_2$ which is not in the range of $S$, it seems to me that the proof works fine too!!. I know that it must be something that I am losing. Can you help me?

Comment: I guess the main idea lies in the starting of natural numbers... The natural numbers have a starting and after that, all the numbers will be successors of a natural number. But if you could understand, only the 1st term or the starting term won't be the successor of a natural number as there is no natural number preceding it. So I guess that's why there is **exactly** one natural number which is not the successor of a natural number.

Comment: Don't assume people know what's in your head. What are the Axioms?

Comment: Sorry. The authors of the book are Cohen & Ehrlich

Comment: If there were a second $u_2$ as you suggest, then the set $M$ in the book's proof, which contains $u$ but not $u_2$, would be a counterexample to the induction axiom $A_3$.